# android:layout_gravity="end" not working when compiling in a real device

Tags: java, android, alignment, layout-gravity

I am trying to align a balloon message to the right/end of the screen, and despite showing it at the right, when seeing in a device, it is to the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/chat_message_top_bottom_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/chat_message_top_bottom_padding"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/chat_message_right_left_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/chat_message_right_left_padding"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@drawable/balloon_shape_sending"
    android:theme="@style/ChatMessagesMessageSending"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:text="Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

In Andriod Studio:

In my device:

[image]

The way it is used to display the messages on the screen is by using `ListView`:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_linear"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message"/>
```

Below the adapter responsible to populate the list:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatroomMessage> {
    MessageAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<ChatroomMessage> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView imgPhoto = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
        TextView tvAuthor = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_author);
        TextView tvMessage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);

        ChatroomMessage message = getItem(position);

        if (message.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            tvMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(imgPhoto.getContext()).load(message.getPhotoUrl()).into(imgPhoto);
        } else {
            tvMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgPhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvMessage.setText(message.getText());
        }

        tvAuthor.setText(message.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you used message view in list or recyclerview?

Comment: @MJM, it is not `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 in which layout you have used this please post that also.. the layout which contains this send and image and all that

Comment: where you have used it post parent view on above xml?

Comment: In `activity_main`, a `ListView` is used.

Comment: show adapter code

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why examples of answers seemed to have worked, but this is my solution:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/balloon_shape_sending"
        android:theme="@style/ChatMessagesMessageSending"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_avg"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_avg"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_chat_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_huge"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_user_alphabet"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_rounded_rect_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_100"
        tools:text="Noice man !" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_user_alphabet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_avg"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_accent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxEms="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_100"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="a" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_left_msg_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_left_msg_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@drawable/recevied_msg_bg"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_right_msg_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_right_msg_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_msg_bg"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```